# How does one create a for loop that makes some data frame or list name based with the i-th element from the for loop in it?

Tags: r, for-loop

In bash I know how to create some new variable using an element from a for loop. For instance:

```
for i in $(seq 1 22); do
echo "processing "$i
cat data-chr${i} | awk '{print $1}' > NEWFILE_${i}; done
```

How do I do something similar in r? In that case I want to create some list based on a selection. And I want the name of the list to contain the i-th element in it, so:

```
for (i in 1:22){
newdata_i <- mydata[ which(mydata$v1==i ), ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function paste might be what you are looking for:

```
my_list <- list()
for(i in 1:5) {
  my_list[[i]] <- data.frame()
  names(my_list)[i] <- paste("name_", i, sep = "")
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the last part? For instance, "names" is that a function that magically makes "my_list1"?

Comment: No, it is just a character, since it is wrapped with " ". You can insert there whatever you want. For example, if you want to name your dataframe as proceedingsi, you could write paste("proceedings", i, sep = "")

Comment: I wasn't clear. I meant    names(my_list)[i]. Is that a particular r function?

Comment: names() is a function, which grabs the names of your list elements (in this case of the previously created my_list). With [i] you tell R, that it only should grab the name of the ith element of this list. With the assignment arrow <- you assign a new name for the this dataframe.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation.